# Dynamically add pictures to Windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently trying to insert a new `PictureBox` and show it with its associated image.I am creating `PictureBox` every time i open a new image. But it doesn't show after the dialog is closed. I am also trying to store the `PictureBox` objects in a list.
Here is the code I have written :

```
OpenFileDialog FileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        FileDlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png, *.bmp) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png, *.bmp";

        if (FileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();

            picBox.Name = "PictureBox" + m_nPictureBoxCounter.ToString();

            m_picboxList.Add(picBox);

            picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(FileDlg.FileName);

            picBox.BringToFront();

            picBox.Location = new Point(10, 10);

            picBox.Size = new Size(500, 500);

            picBox.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to set the parent of the control to `this` (that is your form). Then it will be visible. Tell me if this works to put it as an answer ;)

Comment: Anyway, if you're gonna show your images one by one, would be more efficient to have only one control and then change it's image to the selected one.

Comment: You probably want to use a FlowLayoutPanel to house those PictureBoxes.  Don't expect to have thousands of them though.

Comment: This did the job. However i need to bring it to the front, because i have one permanent picturebox, and the image should appear on top of the permanent one.

Comment: `picBox.BringToFront();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Btc Sources i figured out the answer. I had to ad :

```
 picBox.Parent = this;

 picBox.BringToFront();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add picturebox into a control, i.e.:

```
    this.controls.add(picBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    OpenFileDialog FileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();    
    FileDlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png, *.bmp) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png, *.bmp";

        if (FileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var picBx = new PictureBox();
            picBx.ImageLocation = FileDlg.FileName;
            this.Controls.Add(picBx);
        }
```

That should put you in the right place.  You can adjust position and other properties as you see fit.